.NET Core 6 app asking for app host version 6.0.13 to be installed when 6.0.19 is installed
I have updated a .NET 4.8 WPF project to .NET Core 6, and this is my first experience with .NET 6.
It works fine on my machine which has two versions of NET6 installed:

Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.19

Deploying (via xcopy) to another machine which only has Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.19 installed and I'm getting an error

You must install .NET Desktop Runtime application App host version 6.0.13

I'm getting nowhere trying to find an answer online as all suggestions are that .NET 6 is .NET 6.
I've done a find all on my solution but can't find a reference to 6.0.13.
Is there a setting in a file I need to change to specify 6.0.19 rather than 6.0.13? (or even a setting to tell it to use the version that is installed?)
Edit:
I can see under Dependencies -> Frameworks -> Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref that it's using the version under the 6.0.13 folder rather than the 6.0.19 folder. I imagine if I can change the reference then it will build against 6.0.19 but I can't figure out where to change the folder path.

Could you please  help check the cspro file within the project(or click the application name if you open your project via Visual Studio) to see whether it Specified Runtime Version like <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.13</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>? If there's no specified version in csproj file, could you please help delete the bin and obj folder in the application and rebuild the project then try again?

No, <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.13</RuntimeFrameworkVersion> was not present.

thank you for your confirmation, have you tried to delete the bin and obj folder and rebuild the app?

I have deleted the bin and obj folders and rebuilt the app but now getting: Error (active) NETSDK1112 The runtime pack for Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'any'.
I tried installing the 6.0.19 nuget package but got this error: The package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref 6.0.19 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.

Could you please help confirm whether there's <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref" Version="6.0.xx" /> and <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> in your csproj file?

PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref" Version="6.0.xx" /> - No
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> = <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>

I don't have any good ideas then, but we might just follow up the error message, firstly, let's try to add <PropertyGroup><RuntimeIdentifier>any</RuntimeIdentifier></PropertyGroup>, then let's run dotnet restore --runtime any command. then let's rebuild the project.

I downgraded all the projects to <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> and it now compiles. I still can't install Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref 6.0.19 from Nuget. I now can't check until tomorrow if any of the changes have helped, so will wait until then before trying anything else.

So, it turns out that I had both the x86 and x64 .NET 6 binaries installed on the dev machine but only the x64 binaries on the other machine.
For no particular reason, I thought the binaries in C:\Program Files would have been built as AnyCPU but no, it appears they are strictly x64.
So, with my app compiled as x86 it wouldn't run. Compiled as AnyCPU and it works.
Leaving this here in case someone else has the same issue.
